# Copy text from website using keyboard

Tags: google-chrome, webbrowser-app

Do anyone know of an web application that makes it possible to copy text easily from the web browser using keyboard? E.g. like vimium works for selecting links in the web browser using keyboard.

Edit: to be more specific. How to highlight and copy from web browser using only the keyboard, and not the mouse.

Sorry for being unprecise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need caret browsing.

- press F7 for enable to caret browsing.
- open browsing window then press tab button, then select text using arrow keys. Finally **ctrl+c** and **ctrl+v**.

Answer (score -1):

Highlight the text and push ctrl+c and hit ctrl+v where you want to paste the text.
?

Most web-browsers come with the ability to simply right-click a link and either copy the link address to memory or open in a seperate window/tab.

Comment: OP wanted a solution to not use the mouse either.